# reassigning records in states to different region

Tags: integration, automation, territory-management

So my organization is doing a little reorganization and want to assign three states to a different region. Right now, OK AR and LA are part of the SER. We want to change them to SCR. What first comes to mind is updating the region picklist on each account, and a simple data load would achieve this. I'm curious if anyone has ever dealt with a regional reassignment like this? I'm most interested what else I should be thinking of? We use several integrations such as Pardot, VolunteerHub, OneCause and Melissa Data. We also don't use the Territories functionality of Salesforce yet.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can always write simple Apex script for that. If you environment is well optimised. Here is your simple script.

```
final List<String> states = new List<String>{'OK', 'AR', 'LA'};
List<Account> accountList = [SELECT Id, BillingState FROM Account WHERE BillingState IN: states AND Region__c = 'SER' LIMIT 500];
System.debug(accountList.size());
for(Account account : accountList) {
    account.Region__c = 'SCR';
}
Database.update(accountList);
```

'LIMIT 500' might not be necessary if your environment is well optimised. Or in opposite, query limit will have to be lower.
Please note that script will have to be executed in anonymous apex until debug value will be equal to 0

Comment: note that this will execute triggers &  automations on Account so care should be taken before executing to consider possible side effects.